# Why does create table operation attach owner as 'yugabyte' to a new table yet the database to which am connected has a different owner?

Tags: database, go, datatables, owner, yugabytedb

I have installed yugabytedb in minikube on my laptop and created a database with owner 'Rodgers'.
Then I run the ysqlsh to execute ysql commands from the terminal, one of which is 'CREATE DATABASE ...'.

**Problem**
When I try connecting to the database using an external Go application by providing the application with user as 'Rodgers' and the set password, it fails to connect.
I have found out that the tables created were attached to owner 'yugabyte', not 'Rodgers'.
But the database to which I have connected and from where am running the CREATE DATABASE command belongs to Rodgers.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to rehearse all this using "ysqlsh". When everything works there, connecting from any client program (Python, go, ...) etc will work — as long as you have the right driver. The PostgresSQL drivers work with YugabyteDB.

The following is mainly commands for "ysqlsh" — both SQLs and so-called metacommands (the ones starting with backslash). But occasionally, there are commands that you do from the O/S prompt. So you must read the following carefully and then do what it says after each comment — mainly in "ysqlsh" but a couple of times at the O/S prompt. So you can't simply run the script "lights out".

Start with virgin YB single-node cluster (fresh from "yb-create).

```
$ ysqlsh -h localhost -p 5433 -d yugabyte -U yugabyte
```

Now follow the script.

```
--  Shows two "Superuser" users: "postgres" and "yugabyte" (nothing else).
\du

-- Shows two databases: "postgres" and "yugabyte" (nothing else except "system" databases).
-- Both "postgres" and "yugabyte" databases are owned by "postgres".
\l

-- Create a new "ordinary user and connect as that user.
create user rodgers login password 'p';
alter user rodgers createdb;

-- Now connect to database yugabyte as user rodgers
\c yugabyte rodgers

-- Create a new database and check it's there.
create database rog_db owner rodgers;
\l 

--       Name       |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-- -----------------+----------+----------+---------+-------------+-----------------------
   ...
--  rog_db          | rodgers  | UTF8     | C       | en_US.UTF-8 |
-- ...

-- Now connect to the new "rog_db" database. Works fine.
\c rog_db rodgers

-- Quit "ysqlsh.
\q
```

Connect again. Works fine.

```
$ ysqlsh -h localhost -p 5433 -d rog_db -U rodgers
```

Now carry on with the script.

```
-- Works fine.
create table t(k int primary key);

-- Inspect it. First "\d", then "\d t".
\d
--         List of relations
--  Schema | Name | Type  |  Owner  
-- --------+------+-------+---------
--  public | t    | table | rodgers

\d t
--                  Table "public.t"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-- --------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
--  k      | integer |           | not null | 
-- Indexes:
--     "t_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, lsm (k HASH)

-- This is OK for playing. But terrible for real work.

drop table t;
\c rog_db yugabyte
drop schema public;
\c rog_db rodgers
create schema rog_schema authorization rodgers;
-- For future connect commands.
alter user rodgers set search_path = 'rog_schema';
-- for here and now.
set schema 'rog_schema';
create table t(k int primary key);
\d

--           List of relations
--    Schema   | Name | Type  |  Owner  
-- ------------+------+-------+---------
--  rog_schema | t    | table | rodgers
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I just stepped through all of this using "YB-2.2.0.0-b0" on my laptop (macOS Big Sur). It all worked fine.

Please try this in your minikube env and report back.

*Regards, Bryn Llewellyn, Technical Product Manager at Yugabyte Inc.*